# What are some techniques to improve contextual accuracy of semantic search engine using BERT?

Tags: semantic-web, word-embedding, language-model, bert-language-model

I am implementing a semantic search engine using BERT (using cosine distance) To a certain extend the method is able to find out sentences in a high level context. However when it comes narrowed down context of the sentence, it gives several issues.

Example:
If my search term is "Wrong Product", the search engine might match with sentences like "I bought a washing machine but it was defective".

I understand that the fixes to these is always finding some equilibrium and live with minor errors.

However if there are any rules, techniques which has improved your semantic search implementation accuracy please do share.